# dowload find binary , accidentally deleted /usr/bin/find binary file

Tags: find, rm, binary

I accidentally deleted all some binaries by rm -r f*, when my current directory was /usr/bin/ . So i couldn't install any files including findutils, since 'find' binary is the prerequisite for installations.

Can you help me , where to download or find the binary file for this?

My OS is Mint Olivia 15

Comment: What OS/version/platform are you using?

Comment: I am using linux mint olivia 15

Comment: Do you still have the installation media to hand? Does it have a rescue image? If not, you might be able to find what you need in the Ubuntu or Debian repos. I don't use Linux, so I don't know any more than that, sorry.

Comment: If you solved it, please post an answer explaining what you did.

Comment: As far as I remember, Mint provides the Synaptic Package Manager where you'll find `findutils` which contains `find` too.

Comment: I just reinstalled the findutils after i restarted the system. couldn't do without restarting system though, i don't why?

Comment: You typed `rm -r f*`? What were you hoping to type, `rm -rf *`? That would've broken things even more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are offline and online databases of packages that allow you to search for the package containing a file with a particular name. I don't think Mint implements this, but you can look it up for Ubuntu: online on the [package search page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/), offline with [`apt-file`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/apt-file.1.html).

You don't need `find` to perform most installations. If you find that the lack of `find` is blocking you, download the package and (re)install it manually with `dpkg -i`.

You'll need to reinstall all the packages with missing files. You can find the list of missing files and the corresponding packages by looking through the package lists in `/var/lib/dpkg/info`.

```
apt-get --reinstall install $(grep -l '^/usr/bin/f' /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list | sed -e 's~.*/~~' -e 's~\.list$~~')
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you should use your fine backups that you have taken and use that to restore the missing files.  You have these right?  If you don't, this is something that you need take care of immediately.

Failing the use of backups, the best way to be sure things return correctly is a full reinstall.

Using other methods are generally hit-or-miss, are messy and involve probably a lot more time and you might have problems in the future updating your system as your packaging repositories will then be out of sync.